# Separate project for core modules IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-module

If you are using a module in multiple projects in IntelliJ IDEA is it common practice to make a new project for these modules or to make the modules in one of the projects they are included in?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you're working, whether the common module is developed by you or another team, and other factors. Often, common code is put in a module which produces a jar that the other modules depend upon, and include them all in the same project. This is normal when you're developing the common-code module at the same time as the project and changes are typically committed together (although not necessarily to the same repository or branch). If multiple projects use the common-code module though, and it's developed as a separate library, then it should maybe have a project of its own.

Also, you should probably be using maven when things get this complicated.